# Does meta tags replaced by NGINX performs the same as SSR/SSG meta tags?

Tags: vue.js, seo, single-page-application

It's been some time when SSR application flooded the solution of SPA-SEO problems. But, I was wondering if we can just replace the meta tags used by the bots instead of doing SSR/SSG.

The premise of this scenario is just the SEO problems of SPA and not the actual rendering of the content.
I am using Vite and VueJs3 hosted by NGINX. By using the NGINX replace string I can set the meta tags and the initial body(h1,h2,etc.) needed by the SEO.

**Does the meta tags replaced by the NGINX performs the same as the SSR/SSG meta tags?**

I already research enough to this topic for how many weeks and I am not still satisficed with the answers I got. This actually my last resort.

Here's the sample code for NGINX.

```
location / {
    rewrite ^ /index.html break;
    sub_filter_once off;
    sub_filter '<meta toreplace>' '<meta property="title" content="My website - Home"><meta name="description" content="Home page of my website">';
    sub_filter '<title>toreplace' '<title>My website - Home';
}
```

It does replace the sample meta tags